# ReplaceAll error

Tags: replacement

[image: Code]

i"m trying to replace theta1 and theta2 to x1,x2,x3,x4. What is wrong with this replace method?

Comment: Please post *code* not images. Look [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code) to figure out how. Once you do that we can help you.

Comment: One obvious error is `theta1' ` means nothing.  `theta1'[t]` does

Comment: i tried it using thetat1'[t] -> x2[t], same error occurs